# issue in running diagnostics in azure

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-diagnostics

I was trying to make a dummy diagnostics worker role using the following [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/)

When i run the following command in step 4 :

```
(Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension -ExtensionName 'PaaSDiagnostics' -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics').PublicConfigurationSchema | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath 'WadConfig.xsd'
```

I get the following error in azure powershell, we need the subscription in this command but not sure where.
Also, is there a place where I can find how to make a dummy diagnostics worker role.

```
VERBOSE: 3:32:14 PM - Begin Operation: Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension
Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription
-Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension -ExtensionName 'PaaSDiagnostics' -ProviderNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension], ApplicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Extensions.GetAzureServiceAvailableExt
   ensionCommand

VERBOSE: 3:32:14 PM - Completed Operation: Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension
Out-File : Access to the path 'C:\WadConfig.xsd' is denied.
At line:1 char:148
+ ... rationSchema | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath 'WadConfig.xsd'
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Comment: You should mark Bruno's response as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add your credentials using:

```
add-azureaccount
```

Next, select desired subscription (if you have more than one) using:

```
 Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId <id>
```

Finally, try again.